# Do I need to specify the theme for each activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-styles

If i have specified my Theme for the application  such as so:

```
    <application
    android:name="main_application.GlobalObjects"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Do I then need to specify the Theme again for each activity defined in the manifest file like so:

```
<activity
        android:name="main_application.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>
```

Or do i only need to do this when over riding the applications theme for a single activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Do I then need to specify the Theme again for each activity defined in the manifest file like so
```

No, Once you have defined the `Theme` for the application and applied it in manifest `<application>` tag then there is not need of specifying `Theme` for each `Activity` again.

But if you want different Themes for each activity then in this case you can define separate themes for each activity.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I then need to specify the Theme again for each activity defined in the manifest file like so

No. If you need a specific `Theme` for a particular `Activity` then you can set it on the `Activity`. Otherwise just set it on the `<application>`

[Activity and Application Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use same theme all over the application then setting theme in application tag in manifest is good enough. For example, this part of your code

```
<application
    android:name="main_application.GlobalObjects"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

But if you want to use different theme in different activities then you have to specify the theme like your code

```
<activity
   android:name="main_application.MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name" 
   android:theme="@style/ThemeForThisActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need different theme for each of your activity then YES.
If you need same theme for your application then NO.